Unable to build APK from Kivy program using Buildozer : module 'packaging' has no attribute 'version'
I was trying to build the kivy apk using buildozer buti get an error i couldn't solve.
I'm on windows, so i'm using WSL subsystem to build the apk on linux.
Buildozer spent a long time generating the package and at the end, it seems to succeed, but then it fails for an error.
Here's the last part of the log:
[DEBUG]:        You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[DEBUG]:
[DEBUG]:        BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
[DEBUG]:        33 actionable tasks: 33 executed

[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/adonai/Workout_Tracker/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[DEBUG]:   All possible dists: [<Distribution: name myapp with recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, urllib3)>]
[DEBUG]:   Dist matching name and arch: [<Distribution: name myapp with recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, urllib3)>]
[DEBUG]:   Dist matching ndk_api and recipe: [<Distribution: name myapp with recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, urllib3)>]
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:         myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, urllib3), built for archs (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    # Copying android package to current directory
[INFO]:    # Android package filename not found in build output. Guessing...
[INFO]:    # Found android package file: /home/adonai/Workout_Tracker/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/build/outputs/apk/debug/myapp-debug.apk
[INFO]:    # Add version number to android package
[INFO]:    # Android package renamed to myapp-debug-0.1.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/adonai/Workout_Tracker/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/build/outputs/apk/debug/myapp-debug.apk myapp-debug-0.1.apk
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==1.5.1.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 16, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 682, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 96, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 998, in cmd_debug
    super().cmd_debug(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 108, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 126, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 1310, in build_package
    build_tools_versions, key=packaging.version.parse
AttributeError: module 'packaging' has no attribute 'version'

as you can see, the process fails because module packaging has no attribute version.
I followed a video that built the apk successfully, here's the dependencies i installed:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt-get install unzip
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip ipython3
sudo apt install cython
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt install build-essential libltdl-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev python-dev
sudo pip3 install --upgrade cython
sudo apt-get install zip

I tried different version of the various packages but the problem persists.
Here is a list of dependencies i get with pip3 freeze:
appdirs==1.4.4
attrs==19.3.0
Automat==0.8.0
backcall==0.1.0
blinker==1.4
build==1.2.1
buildozer==1.5.1.dev0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloud-init==20.1
colorama==0.4.3
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.8
Cython==3.0.10
dbus-python==1.2.16
decorator==4.4.2
distro==1.4.0
distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
entrypoints==0.3
httplib2==0.14.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.8
importlib_metadata==7.1.0
incremental==16.10.1
ipython==7.13.0
ipython_genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.15.2
Jinja2==2.10.1
jsonpatch==1.22
jsonpointer==2.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
keyring==18.0.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2
lazr.uri==1.0.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
more-itertools==4.2.0
netifaces==0.10.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
packaging==24.0
parso==0.5.2
pbr==6.0.0
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prompt-toolkit==2.0.10
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycairo==1.26.0
Pygments==2.3.1
PyGObject==3.36.0
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyproject_hooks==1.1.0
pyrsistent==0.15.5
pyserial==3.4
python-apt==2.0.0
python-debian===0.1.36ubuntu1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.22.0
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
SecretStorage==2.3.1
service-identity==18.1.0
sh==1.14.3
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.14.0
ssh-import-id==5.10
systemd-python==234
testresources==2.0.1
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
traitlets==4.3.3
Twisted==18.9.0
ubuntu-advantage-tools==20.3
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.25.8
wadllib==1.3.3
wcwidth==0.1.8
zipp==1.0.0
zope.interface==4.7.1

